# How do you create a button from the color in an image file and position of the mouse?

Tags: python, pygame

So my intent here is to just create a button where the player clicks on the start color to begin, then moves the mouse to the end color. It's an avoider game, where you avoid colors that are not on the path and not the start or end color.

I'm trying to have the mouse hover over the start color (it's green) and click on it to start the game. I was testing it out by setting the position of the cursor, but that didn't seem to work.

I've tried several different methods to get the color. Including drawing a whole extra button, but I couldn't get that where I wanted it to be. It was also not really what I needed.

Here is my code so far. I'm missing a function that would allow the cursor to register what color is underneath it.

At the moment, when running the game it doesn't crash, but it doesn't register what color is below the cursor and what happens when you click on it.

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if mousepressed:
    color = (102, 255, 102)
    screen.set_at(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), color)
    if color and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
       pygame.mouse.set_pos(102, 255)
    else:
    if not color and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pygame.mouse.set_pos(100,100)
```

Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Ariel, welcome to Stack Overflow. To help others answer your question, please could you clarify exactly what doesn't work with the code sample you submitted.

Comment: Hello CyberJacob,
I'm missing a function that would allow the cursor to register what color is underneath it. At the moment, when running the game it doesn't crash, but it doesn't register what color is below the cursor and what happens when you click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of a pixel from a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) at a certain position can be get by [`.get_at()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_at). Use this method, with the Surface object, which is associated to the display (`screen`):

```py
color = screen.get_at(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
```

[`.set_at()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_at) changes to color of the pixel on the Surface, at the specified position. 
In this context, `set_at` means to set a color at a position on the Surface and `get_at` means to get a color at a position from the Surface.